# fast dict lookup

Tags: python, performance

I am writing a bit of `python` code where I had to check if all values in `list2` was present in `list1`, I did that by using `set(list2).difference(list1)` but that function was too slow with many items in the list.

So I was thinking that `list1` could be a dictionary for fast lookup...

So I would like to find a fast way to determent if a list has an item that isn't part of a dict

performance wise is there any difference between

```
d = {1: 1, 2:2, 3:3}
l = [3, 4, 5]

for n in l:
  if not n in d:
    do_stuff
```

vs

```
for n in l:
  if not d[n]:
    do_stuff
```

and please if both of these are rubbish and you know something much quicker, tell me.

Edit1: list1 or d can contain elements not in list2 but not the other way around.

Comment: The two are not the same. Test with `d = {1: 1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:0}` and that will point out the difference between the two to you.

Comment: Note that a dict is not going to be any faster for membership testing, it uses the exact same data structure and algorithm. Your problem is the list.

Comment: The reason your second attempt is not the same as the first is because you are testing the dict's value at a particular key, and -- as Praveen Gollakota astutely notes -- the value of zero evaluates to False.

Comment: The answer may depend somewhat on your anticipated inputs. For example, are matches common, or rare? Are partial matches common, or is it the case that most are mostly different (very few or no similar elements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast way to achieve what you want will be using `all` and a generator comprehension.

```
s_list2 = set(list2)
all_present = all(l in s_list2 for l in list1)
```

This will be advantageous in the case that some elements of list1 are not present in list2.

Some timing. In the case where all values in the first list are contained in the second:

```
In [4]: l1 = range(100)
In [5]: l2 = range(1000)
In [6]: random.shuffle(l1)
In [9]: random.shuffle(l2)
In [20]: %timeit s2 = set(l2); all(l in s2 for l in l1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.4 us per loop
In [21]: %timeit s1 = set(l1); s2 = set(l2); s1.issubset(s2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.3 us per loop
```

If we look at the case where some values in the first list are **not** present in the second:

```
In [2]: l1 = range(1000)
In [3]: l2 = range(100)
In [4]: random.shuffle(l1)
In [5]: random.shuffle(l2)
In [6]: sl2 = set(l2)
In [8]: %timeit ss = set(l2); set(l1) & ss == ss
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.8 us per loop
In [10]: %timeit s1 = set(l1); s2 = set(l2); s2.issubset(s1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.7 us per loop
In [11]: %timeit sl2 = set(l2); all(l in sl2 for l in l1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.58 us per loop
```

You can see that this method is equivalent in performance to the `issubset` in the first case and is faster in the second case as it will short circuit and obviates the need to construct 2 intermediate sets (only requiring one).

Having one large list and one small lists demonstrates the benefit of the gencomp method:

```
In [7]: l1 = range(10)
In [8]: l2 = range(10000)
In [9]: %timeit sl2 = set(l2); all(l in sl2 for l in l1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 230 us per loop
In [10]: %timeit sl1 = set(l1); all(l in sl1 for l in l2)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 us per loop
In [11]: %timeit s1 = set(l1); s2 = set(l2); s1.issubset(s2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 228 us per loop
In [12]: %timeit s1 = set(l1); s2 = set(l2); s2.issubset(s1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 228 us per loop
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what advantage you're describing, but in any case, this repeatedly does linear search in `list2`, so it's awfully slow unless either list is very short.

Comment: -1.  Still two nested loops in there (the second loop is hidden in the in-statement).

Comment: Removed my -1 in light of the edit.  However, your answer does not seem all that different than `set(list2).difference(list1)` which the OP has already tried and found wanting.

Comment: I agree, although I'm not sure we can do better unless in raw python, unless we know something in advance about the data being compared.

Comment: your `all(l in sl2 for l in l1)` is returning False.

Comment: Which is expected. Not all values of `range(1000)` are present in `range(100)`

Comment: But then `s2.issubset(s1)` should return `False` as well, instead it returns `True`.

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out. One thing, do you know if all will return false directly it finds a value that doesn't belong or will it check the hole thing and then return false?

Comment: @Kempe it will return `False` as soon as finding a value, which helps performance. This is known as "short-circuiting"

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the lists to sets and then use the method `issubset()` to check whether one is a subset of another set or not.

```
In [78]: import random

In [79]: lis2=range(100)

In [80]: random.shuffle(lis2)

In [81]: lis1=range(1000)

In [82]: random.shuffle(lis1)

In [83]: s1=set(lis1)

In [84]: all(l in s1 for l in lis2)
Out[84]: True

In [85]: %timeit all(l in s1 for l in lis2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.6 us per loop

In [86]: %timeit s2=set(lis2);s2.issubset(s1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12 us per loop

In [87]: s2.issubset(s1)
Out[87]: True
```

Comment: The timing comparison here is dishonest as you are not including the time needed to create the sets. If lis1 and lis2 were constant we could remove the need to do anything of this by just caching the result.

Comment: @cmh I used the same thing for `all()` as well. see: `all(l in s1 for l in s2)`.

Comment: the benefit of the all solution is that you don't need to transform s2 into a set.

Comment: ... and the downside is that it loops in Python rather than in C ;-)

Comment: But `s1 & s2 == s2` won't short circuit

Comment: You're still not including the time to construct the sets in your timings, which is clearly necessary if we have to build the sets each time we do this comparison.

Comment: I've just realised that our timing is going to be reasonably dependant on the particular shuffle of the range. A more rigorous test would be over a range of shuffles.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting both lists and then walking through them together is O(n log n). i.e.:

```
l1.sort()
l2.sort()

j = 0
for i in range(0,len(l1)):
  while ((j < len(l2)) and (l1[i] == l2[j])):
    j = j+1
  if (j == len(l2)):
    break
  if (l1[i] > l2[j]):
    break

if (j == len(l2)): # all of l2 in l1
```

Now in terms of time complexity, like I said this is O(n log n) because of the sorts (second loop is less than that at O(n)). However it may not be faster in python than the builtin set operations. You'd have to try it.

[BTW, probably a more pythony way to do the last piece with comprehensions if I thought about it]